# Is there something like Touche.js that works with IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, touch

I have been using [touche.js](https://github.com/davidcalhoun/touche) for developing touch-first apps that also work on desktops. I can put a handler on touchstart for example, and it will also fire if the user clicks with their mouse.

A client asked us to support IE10/11 for one of our applications, and it turns out touche.js does not support IE.

As usual, MS does things differently, inventing new events MSPointerDown, etc.

Is there a framework that works like touche, but which also supports IE10's new pointer model?

Comment: I just released: http://benhowdle.im/touche/ Oddly named the same thing, let me know if it helps you!

Comment: The approach you (and the other touché) are using isn't valid any more. In Chrome on touch laptops, the touch events are defined, yet there might *also* be a mouse. I've been working on local modifications to touche (the other one), to deal with this. It's pretty nasty stuff.